# Searching from two mongo collections

Tags: node.js

i am working on MEAN stack application.In my project there is form , in which there are seven fields.Out of 7 fields, 3 are from dept collection and 4 are from user collection.When we search with only one field ,then there is no problem.But when we go for two text field from different collection each,it shows incorrect data.As we know that there is no join operation in mongo db.How can we  join two collection?
Please help me!!!
Let us suppose, these are the seven fields in my form.

Unit Name:
Seller Name:
Code:
Client no:
address:
status
taxid:

In the above list , unit name ,seller name  and code come from office collection.Client no,address,status,taxid come from data collection.
now i am trying to search unit name with status "active".So, now i am trying to search from office collection ,then use id in data collection.

Just ,please tell me how can we perform join in mongodb.How can we perform join operaion in mongodb.

```
 if (string.$and.length > 0) {
                office.find(string).exec(function(err, office) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    } else {

                        for (var i = 0; i < office.length; i++) {
                            ids.push(office[i]._id);

                        }
                        string.$and.push({
                            $or: [{
                                data_id: {
                                    "$in": ids
                                }
                            }
                            }]
                        });
                        if (string1.$and.length > 0) {
                            data.find(string).populate('data_id').exec(function(err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                } else {

                                    res.json(data);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                                                      data.find({
                                $or: [{
                                    data_id: {
                                        "$in": ids
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    data_nu: {
                                        "$in": data_nu
                                    }
                                }]
                            }).populate('data_id').exec(function(err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                } else {

                                    res.json(data_id);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                data.find(string).exec(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return next(err);
                    } else {

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            ids.push(data[i].data_id);
                            data_nu.push(data[i].data_nu);
                        }

                        if (string.$and.length > 0) {
                            office.find({
                                $and: [{
                                    $or: [{
                                        id: {
                                            "$in": ids
                                        }
                                    }, {
                                        data_nu: {
                                            "$in": data_nu
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }, string]
                            }).populate('dataId').exec(function(err, datad) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                } else {

                                    res.json(datad);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            datad.find({
                                $or: [{
                                    id: {
                                        "$in": ids
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    data_nu: {
                                        "$in": data_nu
                                    }
                                }]
                            }).populate('dataId').exec(function(err, datad) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                } else {

                                    res.json(datad);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Please add some code to help us help you. And clearify what you would like to achieve with some example

Answer (score 0):

mongoDB prefers that all of the info about one subject will be in one collection. As you said there aren't any join in mongoDB, 
Trying to JOIN in MongoDB would defeat the purpose of using MongoDB. You could use a [DBref](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) and write your application-level code (or library) so that it automatically fetches these references for you.

Or you could alter your schema and use [embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference).

Your final choice is to leave things exactly the way they are now and do two queries.